# Given a set of python nose tests, is there a way to run or display only the succeeding tests with nose?

Tags: python, testing, nose

I have a large set of tests that have not been maintained for a while. Some percentage of the tests pass, and some fail. I'd like to ask nose to show me only the succeeding tests. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature goes against very strong fundamentals of testing, but you can always output test results into a file by using `--with-xunit` and `--xunit-file=my_test_results.xml` and write a short script that does what you want.